# Seaborn change dot size according to column (like with hue)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I use seaborn to sketch a plot.
My current problem: I am trying to scale the size of the dot relative to the numeric value in a column named "duration". I want to have the dots small which represent a record with a shorter duration and a larger point for a record with longer duration.

Similar to how you can change the color of the points with hue. I don't want to set it statically with `size` parameter.

`sns.swarmplot(x="FOO", y="BAR", data=df, size="DURATION");
plt.show();`

I excpected that the size of the dots scale up according to the duration field. But it gave me an error because size actually expects a float. That means it is not wanting a column name.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a swarmplot. Maybe try [sns.relplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html?highlight=relplot#seaborn.relplot)

Comment: Thanks @NilsSchlüter